# make column and row index in descending order in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I created a table with columns and rows. Currently, the cell(1,1) starts at *top-left* of the table. How to start the count from bottom left?

Here is my code:

```
 <table class="table">
   <tr v-for="row in rows">
        <td v-for="col in cols">
        {{ row }} - {{ col }}
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

See full code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/wpgkabue/

Comment: rearrange your array in a computed value then use that instead.

Comment: @smzapp are you trying for this?
https://jsfiddle.net/rahmbs7u/
Shouldn't the image in bottom right be (1, 8) as row is 1 and col is 8. Same for top left. 8th row and 1 col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example really only counts up to the integer 8. You need focus on the data.

I've changed your data to lists (you can and probably will have objects later):

```
data: {
    rows: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    cols: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
}
```

Then we make a computed property, that returns and reverses your rows variable:

```
sortedRows: function() {
  return this.rows.reverse()
}
```

Then inside the template, we change rows to sortedRows:

```
<tr v-for="row in sortedRows">
  <td v-for="col in cols">
    {{ row }} - {{ col }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Heres the JSfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/procoib/8u0qhy2w/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution. Just change your code to

```
<table class="table">
 <tr v-for="row in rows">
    <td v-for="col in cols">
    {{ 9 - row }} - {{ col }}
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rahmbs7u/

Comment: please check the pair at the bottom righ (8,8)

Comment: @smzapp, Isn't the bottom right 1st row and 8th col. So, shouldn't it be (1-8) only representing 1st row and 8th col. Which value do you want here anyway? Your image is a bit confusing in this context.